# How to count Duplicate IP in a Column in CSV by Python

Tags: python, ip, wireshark, pcap, dpkt

I have program for extract PCAP ARP src_ip and Dest_IP and save in CSV file. i need code how to count Number of Times Src_IP is request to dest_ip (Example 192.168.0.1 src_IP try to connected 10 times with Dest_ip). so how to count duplicates IP in a Column. or how to count src to dest IP or any other idea for count duplicate IP in a Column pls.

below code I need to count number of times src to target

```
    for ts, buf in pcap:

        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)

        # If the packet is not arp

        if eth.type != 2054:
            continue
        try:
            arp = eth.arp
        except Exception as e:
            continue

        packet_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M:%S")

        src = dpkt.socket.inet_ntoa(arp.spa)
        tgt = dpkt.socket.inet_ntoa(arp.tpa)
```

Comment: You can use the `collections.Counter` class: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your reply. here counter can count from list. but i need count from csv column. so it will work?

Comment: You can use the `csv` module to read a CSV file! Python has quite a bit of useful functionality built into its standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks Eric for your suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to load desired IPs into a list and then do something like:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(ip_list)
```

Comment: Hi Toni, Thanks for your reply. check the code i have added now. may how to count src - > target .....number of times

Comment: are `src` and `target` both lists with IPs?

Comment: Yes src and target both are IP's but not in list. i tried to print src and target  but its print as list but single single rows list. pls check the code i have added the problem statement.   src = dpkt.socket.inet_ntoa(arp.spa) ......here src contains all src IP but print as a list row basis.